# Redirecting to a page after ajax post. And then accessing values from $_SESSION: session is empty

Tags: php, jquery, session

I'm posting 3 arrays of data to a php file(checkout.php) on the server via jquery post.

```
$.post("checkout.php", {items_name : JSON.stringify(items_name), items_price : JSON.stringify(items_price), items_amount : JSON.stringify(items_amount)}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
//those three are arrays(items_name, items_price & items_amount
});
window.location.href = "checkout.php";
```

Then I receive the data arrays in the checkout.php and store them in $_SESSION.

```
$items_name = json_decode($_POST['items_name']);
$items_price = json_decode($_POST['items_price']);
$items_amount = json_decode($_POST['items_amount']);

session_start();
$_SESSION['items_name'] = $items_name;
$_SESSION['items_price'] = $items_price;
$_SESSION['items_amount'] = $items_amount;
```

When the page redirects to checkout.php after making the jquery post, when i try to access data from session, it doesn't show anything.

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Place session_start() at the top of the PHP file before any other code.

Comment: What do you mean by "both places"?

Comment: @JayBlanchard is right that it's good practice to put `session_start()` at the top, but unless you have any whitespace before your opening php tag or any other output sent to the browser before this point, it should not affect your ability to store in or retrieve from the session, so it may not be your problem in this case.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I had added session_start(); already. Still not working.

Comment: I had used if(isset($_POST)) to assign $items_name. and else print_r($_SESSION). So I had put session_start right after if() and else.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `post` call is executed asynchronously, so your code continues down to the redirect immediately without waiting for the php script to finish on the server. Add your redirect to the success/complete callback for `post`.

```
$.post("checkout.php", {items_name : JSON.stringify(items_name), items_price : JSON.stringify(items_price), items_amount : JSON.stringify(items_amount)}, function(data){
    // whatever
    window.location.href = "checkout.php";
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't think about that, but I did it now. i used `.done(function){ window.location = "checkout.php"}`. still not seeing any result.

Answer (score 0):

checking if only $_POST is set, doesn't work. But making it more specific works.

```
if(isset($_POST['items_name'])){
    //Code here
}
```

Now this works fine.